# detecting emotions in sentiment analysis python

Tags: python, nlp

I was curious if anyone had any thoughts about how one might detect major emotions displayed in a text? Are there any python packages or examples that do this?

TO clarify:

I know that there is already something called sentiment analysis. However, I'm noticing this only looks at positive/negative sentiment.
I'm wondering if it's actually possible to find emotions (like sadness, joy, despair, etc) linked to certain texts.

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out about this? I've found sentiment analysis isn't reliable enough for my needs

Comment: @user Try VAD based multi-dimensional analysis for deriving Emotions. Related project(s): [SenPy](https://github.com/gsi-upm/senpy), [EmoBank corpus](https://github.com/JULIELab/EmoBank)

Answer (score -2):

as learning refer [link](http://andybromberg.com/sentiment-analysis-python/)

As complete example - [git](https://github.com/sebm/twitty-city)

Comment: do you know if it's possible to detect specific EMOTIONS (like anger, sadness, fear...)?